# Working on adjacent cells in a Quadtree on GPU

Tags: arrays, gpu, quadtree

In this video from SpaceX (https://youtu.be/txk-VO1hzBY) they describe dividing a region into rectangles as you would using a quadtree.

They then talk about running a calculation for each cell in this presumed quadtree that depends on that cell's 4 neighbors using GPU.

Knowing the limits of GPU code (data must come as an array and you must try to access elements in the array in an simple consistent order), how does one pass a quadtree of data into a GPU in array form?

Are there well-known algorithms to work on quadtrees like this?

Comment: [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Adam_Lichtl2/publication/283514490_High_Performance_Multiresolution_Simulation_and_Visualization/links/563ccb9c08ae45b5d2898c76.pdf) by SpaceX engineers suggests that what they are using is not a quadtree. Since these high performance simulations are probably part of SpaceX's "secret sauce", my guess is that they are unlikely to make the exact details known.

Comment: Not sure of quadtrees, but the technique you mention (of dividing a region into sub-regions and then performing some computation on each subregion based on its neighbours) is used in stencil computations as well as adaptive mesh refinement, both of which have been implemented on the GPU. You might want to start there.

Comment: Do you mean 4 subregions, You wrote 4 neigbours, A quad cell can have  more then 4 adjacent neighbour cells.

Answer (score 0):

An array based quad tree is called "Linear Quadtree".

see also e.g https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/linearquadtr.html)
(A google search will give you some papers to read)